# XML Parser in android

Tags: android, xml-parsing, android-parser

I need to know what is the best way to parsing XML file in android, I know there is 3 parser (XMLPullParser, Dom Parser and Sax parser) so whats the different between it and if there any code to do that.

Comment: there are lots and lots of articales regarding this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893392/android-dom-vs-sax-vs-xmlpullparser-parsing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sax Parser :** Simple API of XML Parse node to node, using top-down traversing, parse without storing xml, Faster compared to Dom Manipulating of node like insertion or deletion is allowed. Needs SAXParserFactory

**Dom Parser :** Document Object Model Stores entire xml in memory before processing,   traverse in any direction, Manipulating of node like insertion or deletion is NOT allowed. Needs DocumentBuilderFactory

**Pull Parser:** It provides more control and speed from the above two.

Answer (score 1):

Android training recommends XMLPullParser.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

> We recommend XmlPullParser, which is an efficient and maintainable way to parse XML on Android.

They also give some code examples.